# Solving Peer Dependency requirements in react-native

Tags: ios, node.js, react-native, react-redux

I have the following `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "MovieReview",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.13.1",
    "moment": "^2.13.0",
    "native-base": "0.4.7",
    "react": "15.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.27.2",
    "react-native-button": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-code-push": "^1.12.1-beta",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.1.6",
    "react-native-gifted-spinner": "0.0.4",
    "react-native-modalbox": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^3.30.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-webview-android": "^1.1.6",
    "react-redux": "4.4.5",
    "redux": "^3.5.2",
    "redux-persist": "^3.2.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "rx": "^4.1.0",
    "youtube-api": "^2.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "mocha": "^2.5.3",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.3.3",
    "remote-redux-devtools-on-debugger": "^0.4.6"
  }
}
```

I am trying to install the dependencies in this `package.json`. I have  `node v4.0.0` installed in my system.
My `react-native` version is `0.27.2`:

```
$ react-native --version
react-native-cli: 1.0.0
react-native: 0.27.2
```

I am getting the following dependency errors when I try run `npm install` in my project folder:

```
$ sudo npm install
Password:
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/triple.s/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/bin/node" "/Users/triple.s/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.2
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package react@15.1.0 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer native-base@0.4.7 wants react@15.0.2 - 15.1.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-native@0.27.2 wants react@15.1.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-redux@4.4.5 wants react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-0

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/triple.s/Desktop/MovieReview/npm-debug.log
```

I tried changing the `react` version to `15.0.0` and `15.0.2` by modifying `package.json`, but still getting the same kind of error.

**EDIT:**

I updated `npm` using  `npm install -g npm` and tried to install dependencies, 
the following warning messages were thrown:

```
npm WARN native-base@0.4.7 requires a peer of react@15.0.2 - 15.1.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-native@0.27.2 requires a peer of react@15.1.0 but none was installed.
```

Does that mean, `native-base` and `react-native` not installed?

Comment: You have the old version of `npm`. Update it too: `npm install -g npm` and try `npm install` again and let's see what the error changes into.

Comment: updated `npm`.. this time getting some warnings

Comment: `native-base` and `react-native` is installed but as the warning says, they require `react 15.1.0`. But your package.json has that exact version. Can you try installing it manually using `npm install --save react@^15.1.0`